# Database structure for stock trading website?

Tags: php, sql

I have created a simple stock trading simulation website. Users can sign up and buy/sell stocks. Now, I've come to a problem. When a use buys a stock (can be more than one share), how do I put this into a database?

This is a bit of a challenge because each user can buy any stock that exists and they can buy any quantity.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to store into a db:

Stocks owned by username1261817

Symbol: Quantity

goog: 3

yhoo: 8

aapl: 3

etc...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the FAQ on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. This question is too broad to answer, and you should ask questions about what you've tried, rather than "how do I do [x]"

Comment: Do you need to store a record of each buy or sell that occurs?  Or do you just need the number of each type of stock that each user holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to design your table like how a shopping cart would do. Include fields - userid (comes from user table), stock symbol, quantity, stock price at the time of purchase, date purchased. This will help you generate the necessary reports like total stocks of one type, total stocks owned by a user etc.

Comment: So this means I have to create a new table for every user?

Comment: @user1261817: no. You have a user table (userid, name). Then the table described by janenz00 would be (userid, ticker, quantity, price, transaction_date). That's two tables, no matter how many users you have and no matter how many purchases were made. You are probably going to want to read a tutorial on using databases.